# in Bash，How to check user login

Tags: bash

If use bash script how to record the number of logged in users every 5 minutes.  Each measurement needs to be appended to a text file.  There should be one line of text for each measurement, formatted as follows.

Fri Oct 11 13:12:04 EDT 2011 8 users

Comment: It looks more like a feature specification than a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will count multiple logins of a single user as multiple matches *i.e* if you ssh into a machine 3 times with the same account this will show `3 users`

`echo $(date) $(who | awk '{print $1}' | wc -l) users >> log.txt`

To treat multiple logins from one username as one match this is what you want:

`echo $(date) $(who | awk '{print $1}' | uniq | wc -l) users >> log.txt`